# Enforce bluetooth security and authentication using BlueZ

Tags: security, authentication, bluetooth, bluez, hci

I'm using `BlueZ 5.49` and trying to connect, pair, and pass information between two different bluetooth devices.
It's seems like i have problem with enforcing security and authentication between the two.

I'm configuring each `hci` device with:
`hciconfig hci0 pscan auth encrypt` which as i read, is setting the device to security mode 3.

In addition i'm creating manualy this path in both sides: `/var/lib/bluetooth/<local_bdaddr>/<remote_bdaddr>/info` with `LinkKey`.

I've noticed that if i'm creating the path for only one device, and then trying to connect using `rfcomm connect` from the device without the `info`file, the connection succeed, even though the device is lacking the `info` file which containts the `LinkKey`.
If i'm trying `rfcomm connect` from the device with the `info` file i'm getting `Key Exchange` Error, which is acceptable since the other device doesn't have the key.

**My base line is that it seems that security and authentication are not enforced.**

**Many Thanks,
Liad**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `hci` device is by default set to work in *Secure Simple Pairing* also known
as `sspmode`. Simple Pairing originaly generated to support devices that can't insert pin  code during pairing process (such as headset).

Hence when a device is in `sspmode` enabled, it use a default pin key - say 0000, and then based on the pin, generating `LinkKey` to encrypt and authenticate, and thus not truely enforcing authentication as i mentioned before.

The line `hciconfig hci0 sspmode disable` is disabling the Secure Simple Pairing mode, and finally enforce authentication using the static `LinkKey` you supply
in the info file which located in `/var/lib/bluetooth/<your_mac>/<remote_mac>/info`.